# combinations of substrings in a string

Tags: ruby, combinations

How can I find all possible combinations of a set of strings in a given string?

```
strings = ["ab","aa","ab","bb","ba","aba","aab"]
given_string = "abaababbab"
```

has to return:

```
[
 ["ab","aa","ba","bb","ab],
 ["ab","aab","ab","ba","bab"]
 ["aba","aba","bb","ab"]
]
```

Comment: Do you mean all combinations of characters (e.g. "abc" would return "abc", "acb", bac", "bca", cba"), do you mean all concatenations of all strings (e.g. ["dog", "cat"] returns ["dogcat", "catdog"], or all combinations of all characters, and all concatenations?

Comment: how it can be "bab" in your return if `strings` doesn't include "bab"?

Comment: This looks like it calls for a recursive function (apologies if you'd got that far already).  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A rough idea might be something like this:

```
strings.select do |s|
  given_string.index(s)
end
```

This would give you:

```
["ab", "aa", "ab", "bb", "ba", "aba", "aab"]
```

I'm not sure if you're hunting for duplicates here or not. You may end up in a computationally complex problem if you're not careful as this sort of thing is what makes DNA sequencing extraordinarily compute-intensive.

Answer (score -1):

The following:

```
strings = ["ab","aa","ab","bb","ba","aba","aab"]
@strings = strings.uniq!
@given_string = 'abaababbab'
@given_length = @given_string.length

def parse
  @parses.each do |parse|
    before = parse.pop # offset of the part that hasn't yet been parsed
    @strings.each do |str|
      next unless m = @given_string.match(str, before)
      first, last = m.offset(0)
      next unless first == before
      if last == @given_length
        @completed_parses.push([*parse, str])
      else
        @new_parses.push([*parse, str, last])
      end
    end
  end
  @parses = @new_parses
  @new_parses = []
  parse unless @parses.empty?
end

@parses = [[0]]
@new_parses = []
@completed_parses = []
parse
p @completed_parses
```

will give you:

```
[["aba", "aba", "bb", "ab"], ["ab", "aa", "ba", "bb", "ab"]]
```

I don't get why you have `["ab","aab","ab","ba","bab"]` in your answer.